Can I pay everywhere in Singapore with an electronic wallet?
I have recently installed Google's electronic wallet (GPay). I do not have much experience with it. I am traveling to Singapore soon. I will mainly need to pay for (1) public transportation, (2) taxis, (3) grocery stores, (4) tourist attractions e.g. museums.
Will I be able to pay for all of these using my GPay, so that I can leave my credit card at the hotel room?

I was a Singapore resident and I think I can answer this. I have seen people use mobile wallets exclusively everywhere. Its widely refereed to as “paywave”—an umbrella term for contactless credit card and mobile wallet (which stores credit card, like google pay).

Public transportation.

Yes. You can use phone and it works fine. If you are staying long term, I suggest to get a MRT card, as they charge extra for foreign cards.

Taxis.

Yes. They take phone. Just say magic keyword - paywave. You can book via grab for convenience though.

Grocery stores.

All major grocery stores (Fairprice, Coldstorage, ShengShiong, Mustafa, 711 etc.) will take cards/wallets. However, small local shops may not take it. You probably need cash or NETS compatible card (local debit card).

Tourist attractions e.g. museums.

Yes. All tourist attractions take it. You can book online in advance though.
These places don't take cards/wallets (usually): Hawker centers, street side vendors (like in Little India and Chinatown), small local stores.
I advice to keep a small amount of cash as a backup.

I have seen people use mobile wallets exclusively everywhere. Its widely refereed to as "paywave" Some of what you believe you saw may be PayNow/PayLah which requires a local bank account and so may not be available to tourists.

I know the difference. PayNow/PayLah is QR code based. I was exclusively referring to adding credit card to mobile wallet and using that.

By "MRT card" you mean EZ-Link?

Yes. Its a prepaid card available for purchase at MRT stations, which can be used for all transport purposes and more.

Electronic payments/tap to pay is ubiquitous in Singapore and you will be able to pay for everything on your list with your phone. Locals call it "paywave"; this is technically Visa's trademark, but it's used generically.
All that said, I would still keep a credit card on my back pocket in case you run out of battery or something. There's also one additional category of places you should visit, namely hawker centres, where Visa/MC are not accepted in any form and you still need Singapore dollars cash.
Update for all the pedants in the comments: Yes, Singapore has some merchants who refuse credit card payments but accept the local debit card network (NETS) or any of a wide variety of app/QR based systems (PayNow, GrabPay, etc). For a tourist on a short trip, there's no point even trying to set up any of these, just pay cash instead.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Many food court and hawker centre stalls may not accept Google Pay and these are a key part of the Singapore experience. (Many may accept PayNow/PayLah—which is not available to tourists because it requires a local bank account—but not GPay or credit cards.)
Otherwise, you can use GPay for (1) public transportation, (2) taxis, (3) major grocery stores, and (4) tourist attractions, albeit possibly with foreign card fees.
Many but far from all restaurants will also accept GPay.

GrabPay worked fine for me at hawker centres, and does not require a local bank account.

@MJeffryes Many hawkers are still cash only and accept no electronic payments whatsoever.

@lambshaanxy I was addressing specifically the part of the answer 'Many may accept PayNow/PayLah—which is not available to tourists because it requires a local bank account—but not GPay or credit cards'. Any hawker who accepts PayNow can be paid by GrabPay, in my experience, because of the unified payment QR codes. I found only a minority of hawkers won't accept QR codes, but yes, they exist. But that wasn't what my comment was about anyway.

In case of network or terminal problems your electronic wallet can fail while a card still works.
That is a good reason to carry your card.
In case of network problems, or sellers without a terminal, cash will still work when cards fail. Carrying cash might be your preferred second option, in which case the card will be less needed.
I have not been in Singapore, this is general worldwide smart thinking.

Not exactly. The only reason why it can be beneficial to carry a card is that it needs no battery. Apart from that, it's the same. A phone doesn't have to be connected to the internet for the contactless payments to work. It can even be in flight mode. If the terminal works and accepts your card, it'll also accept your card virtually (in a phone or similar device), I'd say with even greater probability. Of course, carrying some cash is still highly recommended.

One of the local streetfood businesses here had a problem with his terminal which did not accept contactless but did accept cards, recently. So I say carrying the card is worth it.

Not sure who you're talking about, but I've never heard about a terminal rejecting a phone payment, and afterwards accepting the same card presented physically. Of course, feel free to carry your card (I'd do the same - wouldn't leave it in the hotel).

@Johnnyjanko Technically GPay uses a virtual card number that is not the same as your actual card number. I agree this makes no difference in practice, but there definitely are a few merchants around whose old terminals support chip and PIN but not tap to pay.

@Johnnyjanko There is no such thing as a phone wallet and a physical card being the same card. All electronic wallets use intermediary virtual cards; the terminal does not see any connection to your physical card at all. But a terminal rejecting a phone payment, and afterwards accepting the same card as the one the phone wallet is connected to is far from unheard of.

@lambshaanxy There are also terminals which accept physical cards but not digital wallets. It used to be the case with (i)Zettles that they didn’t take Apple Pay but worked fine with cards; a restaurant near where I live is still the same to this day; and the hotel I stayed at in Birmingham earlier this year couldn’t get Apple Pay to work either, but when I used my physical card, it worked at once. It’s absolutely a thing.

@lambshaanxy if a terminal only accepts chip and PIN, then you absolutely cannot pay with your phone, but also not with a physical card in a contactless way...

@JanusBahsJacquet In that hotel in Birmingham, is it possible to use a physical card for a contactless payment? If yes, I concede. If not, it simply means it doesn't support contactless payments, whether with a physical card or with a mobile phone.

@Johnnyjanko Yes, I paid contactless. Apart from when I have to use my PIN with any new card at least once before I can use them for certain online services (and therefore insert the card into the terminal, to force the PIN), I’ve been exclusively contactless for at least five or six years. I don’t even remember the last time I saw a terminal that didn’t support tapping. The hotel, my local restaurant and (i)Zettles before the firmware update (or whatever it was that added wallet functionality) all support(ed) contactless, even when Apple Pay doesn’t work.
